# output number giving exception input string was not in a correct formate

Tags: c#

I have some regex to convert a string from

```
RRP ?142 - Now ?113 to just 142
```

For this the code which I am using is

```
private Regex _originalPriceRegex = new Regex(@"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?");
```

I am getting the exception when the program is return the value from the function below

```
private string LookForOrignalPrice(HtmlNode node)
{
    string text = node.InnerText;
    Match priceMatch = _originalPriceRegex.Match(text);

    if (priceMatch.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("++++++price is " + priceMatch + "++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        return priceMatch.Groups[1].Value; //Issue arising here
    }
    return null;
}
```

Code for calling the function is

```
{ProductProperties.priceOriginal, new HtmlElementLocator("//td[@class='tdRow1Color']//td[@class='plaintext']//text()[starts-with(., 'RRP')] | descendant::td[@class='tdRow1Color']/descendant::td[contains(text(), '£')] | //span[@style='font-weight:bold;color:White;']",
                customValueHandler: new CustomValueHandler(LookForOrignalPrice))
```

The issue seem to be arriving when the function is returns the value for the function because it is returning just a number is there a way to covert the string in the function to a decimal or int to get around the exception.
Thanks for any advice you can give

Comment: Are you sure that's where the exception is coming from? A `FormatException` is usually something I'd expect to see from `int.Parse` or `double.Parse`.

Comment: can you please show the code from where you are invoking above method?

Comment: Running breakpoints on the code it seens to be coming up there when the function is returning the value, I have not used the int.Parse or double.Parse in the code

Comment: Added the code where the method is being called

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace verbatim? I'm with Matt in thinking that this doesn't seem to be a likely palce to see this exception.

Comment: @MattBurland: I assume it is passing in a delegate/method that it is then using. That line you quoted could make perfect sense to me. Not to say that its right, just that it isn't inherently wrong.

Comment: @Chris: You're right - then we need to see `CustomValueHandler` to see what it's doing with the delegate. And, technically, that's not the code where the function was called.

Comment: dear can you please show the `CustomValueHandler` constructor code?

Comment: @MattBurland: Hopefully a nice stack trace will clear up all these confusions...